# How to access a javascript function in angular2 template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I have a javascript(.js) file with set of functions in one object.

Now i want to call a function which is (.js) file with (click)event in  angular2 template.
how to call?? 
IES.js
..........

```
var IES = IES|| {};

    IES.execute = function (functionName, args) {
  if(arguments.length>2){
      args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
  }
  var context = IES;
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}

  IES.do =  function(){
        console.log('In Do function');
    }
    IES.test = function(){
       console.log('In test function');
    }
    IES.test.hello = function(){
      console.log('In hello function');
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you have tried and what you want to achieve

Comment: Make you object exportable and then import it to your component class. Wrap your logic (with your functions) into the function e.g. Func1 and bind it to (click)="Func1()"

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in bindings can only access members of the components class instance. You can assign the function from your JS library to a field in your class and then bind the `click` event to that field:

```
<button (click)="f()">click me</button>
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  f = fFromJsLib;
}
```